# Problems to install nginx-full on debian 8

Tags: debian, nginx

I have some problems to install nginx pkg (nginx-full) on debian jessie

```
# apt-get install nginx-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nginx-common
Suggested packages:
  fcgiwrap nginx-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx-common nginx-full
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 510 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1.271 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://debian.c3sl.ufpr.br/debian/ jessie/main nginx-common all 1.6.1-1 [83,6 kB]
Get:2 http://debian.c3sl.ufpr.br/debian/ jessie/main nginx-full amd64 1.6.1-1+b1 [427 kB]
Fetched 510 kB in 1s (266 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-common.
(Reading database ... 170540 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.6.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.6.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-full.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-full_1.6.1-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-full (1.6.1-1+b1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up nginx-common (1.6.1-1) ...
Setting up nginx-full (1.6.1-1+b1) ...
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

# systemctl status nginx.service
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sex 2014-09-05 11:39:46 BRT; 1s ago
  Process: 2972 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

#journalctl -xn
No journal files were found.
```

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add the output of 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn'

Comment: # systemctl status nginx.service is there, and the journalctl -xn returns "No journal files were found."

Comment: I had the same issue, since I installed lighttpd first. It would be great, if nginx would provide a better error message, though @Shutupsquare: for me that output was useless and didn't allow concluding that the port was already blocked...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A similar issue was reported on [Debian bug #754407](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754407). In the end it was just the port 80 being taken by other process (Apache2). Might this be your case as well?

Comment: Having read the bug, this really should fail more gracefully and informatively. It should also be possible to switch to another port if the current port is in use. I think postgresql does something like this for example.

Comment: The bug has been fixed at version 1.6.1-2. Now, all things work perfectly

Comment: @gnomex nope, 1.9.10-1 in Stretch and I had to stop `apache2` to install `nginx-full`.

Comment: In my case Varnish was using port 80 as I tried to install nginx for 443. Thanks for the tip

Comment: 2020 and I just got this error. Thank you !

Answer (score 22):

Stop apache2

```
service apache2 stop
```

then install nginx

```
apt-get install nginx
```

Then celebrate it!

Answer (score 16):

in my case I executed

`sudo apt-get remove nginx* --purge`
after that I installed nginx-common

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-common
```

then I installed nginx

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

after this I typed ip in browser and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I DO NOT have Apache, and nothing else was blocking my port 80.
I could NOT install nginx with

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

nor with

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-common nginx-full
```

After one week I stumbled over this little blog: https://etc.banana.fish/?p=75

In this blog, the solution is:

1. Install nginx-common: `sudo apt-get install nginx-common`
2. Remove `listen [::]:80 default_server;` from **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default** (I made this using the root-user)
3. Just to be sure, I did reboot my server.
4. Just to be sure twice, I did `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
5. Now I finally called `sudo apt-get install nginx-full` and it worked!

Afterwords I could see the Titlescreen of nginx, when I typed in the IP of my remote server!

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this issue when `apt-get remove nginx` and `apt-get automove nginx`, and after than I manually remove the nginx folder. When I `apt-get install nginx` again, this issue comes out.

```
~# apt-get install
```

> nginx Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree        Reading state information... Done nginx is
>   already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
>   and 140 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or removed. After this
>   operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to
>   continue? [Y/n] y Setting up nginx-full (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ... Job for
>   nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and
>   'journalctl -xn' for details. invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action
>   "start" failed. dpkg: error processing package nginx-full
>   (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
>   error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>   nginx:  nginx depends on nginx-full (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u4) | nginx-light
>   (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u4) | nginx-extras (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u4); however:
>   Package nginx-full is not configured yet.   Package nginx-light is not
>   installed.   Package nginx-extras is not installed.  nginx depends on
>   nginx-full (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u4.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u4.1~)
>   | nginx-extras (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u4.1~); however:   Package nginx-full
>   is not configured yet.   Package nginx-light is not installed.
>   Package nginx-extras is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while
>   processing:  nginx-full  nginx E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned
>   an error code (1)

and

```
~# systemctl status nginx.service
```

> nginx.service - A high performance
>   web server and a reverse proxy server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)    Active: failed
>   (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-03-21 04:35:29 EDT; 1min 33s ago
>   Process: 19912 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on;
>   master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 18408
>   (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Mar 21 04:35:29 dayinhu nginx[19912]: nginx: [emerg] open()
>   "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) Mar 21
>   04:35:29 dayinhu nginx[19912]: nginx: configuration file
>   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed Mar 21 04:35:29 dayinhu systemd[1]:
>   nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 Mar 21
>   04:35:29 dayinhu systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web
>   server and a reverse proxy server. Mar 21 04:35:29 dayinhu systemd[1]:
>   Unit nginx.service entered failed state.

It's said the nginx.conf lost, I tryed many times with no success.

Finally I fixed by,

```
apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full
apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: This worked for me too! Turns out my copy of nginx was corrupted or something.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the error is the server has IPv6 disabled. just edit nginx configuration files to fix ( for example : /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ) and restart nginx demon.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The advice about Apache wasn't relevant, as I'd actively uninstalled it during setup.

Turns out I was seeing the result of a conflict between nginx's config file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and the service script at `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`.

Specifically, the service script was starting nginx with some options, including `daemon on`:

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
...
[Service]
...
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
...
```

I ran `/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'` directly on the terminal and got the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "daemon" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

I took a look in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and found (on line 1):

```
daemon off;
```

Commenting this out and running `sudo apt-get -f install` resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To install NGINX without stopping previous web server do :

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

To have the config, then :

```
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Then redo the install :

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

And it works !

Answer (score -2):

1. if you have skype: switch skype port `80` to `443`
2. stop apache2 service
3. install nginx
4. restart apache2
5. apt-get update